# Nested select query too slow for result

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, database-administration

The following query is working fine for 10 records but takes time for more records:

```
SELECT s.a, s.b, s.c
FROM
(SELECT abc FROM h1
WHERE a IN
(SELECT a FROM h1 GROUP BY a HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT b) = 1 )) s
```

Can anyone give it a boost?

Comment: That may not be the best way to write the query. To save us guessing what you are trying solely based on your code how about posting sample data and expected output as text.

Comment: I just noticed you accepted an answer from a previous question on the same topic - what was wrong with that answer that you raised another?

Answer (score 0):

First, do not use unnecessary subqueries in the `FROM`, so write this as:

```
SELECT h.a, h.b, h.c
FROM h1 h
WHERE a IN (SELECT hh.a FROM h1 hh GROUP BY hh.a HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT hh.b) = 1);
```

This will still have really lousy performance.  What you want is all rows where the `a` values have a single `b`.  So:

```
select h.*
from h1 h
where not exists (select 1
                  from h1 hh
                  where hh.a = h.a and hh.b <> h.b
                 );
```

Much better.  Then for this query you want an index on `h1(a, b)`.

You can also write this using a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT h.a, h.b, h.c
FROM h1 h JOIN
     (SELECT hh.a
      FROM h1 hh
      GROUP BY hh.a
      HAVING MIN(hh.b) = MAX(hh.b)
     ) hh
     ON hh.a = h.a;
```

This only does the aggregation once.  And I it should also take advantage of the same index.